# How to invert a an incorrectly modeled 1:1 relationship?

Tags: sql

I have an incorrectly modeled 1:1 relationship between two tables:

```
Table: Customer
* id (bigint)
* ...

Table: Address
* id
* customer_id (bigint)       <--- FOREIGN KEY
* street (varchar)
* ...
```

The real-world relationship is so that a customer may have one address or not. However, with the current data model, it would be possible to assign multiple addresses to a customer. We do not do this at the moment, so the data could be migrated to this:

```
Table: Customer
* id (bigint)
* address_id (nullable bigint)
* ...
```

Is it possible to make this migration in one transaction, using purely SQL code? I would like to avoid an intermediate state where we have both relationships and migrate the customers one-by one. That is the best idea I came up with so far.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Why don't you simply add UNIQUE-index on customer_id in the Address-table?

Comment: Generally several customers can share the same address. Are you sure it should be modeled with an 1:1 relation in your DB?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood so far is you want to add address_id column in customer table. If there is more than one address for a customer then you might need to select only one address. Here I am considering last address.

```
update Customer
set address_id=(select max(id) from Address a where a.customer_id=Customer.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually leave your data model as is and just add a unique constraint to `address`:

```
alter table address unq_address_customer unique (customer_id);
```

This is not ideal, but it does enforce the unique constraint with minimal changes to the data model.

That said, I would question why you want only one address per customer.  Have you considered these situations?

- Customers whose "delivery" address and whose "billing" address are different.
- Customers who move.
- Customers whose address changes although they do not move, say due to postal code reassignments or street name changes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The situation is that we definitely will need only one current address per customer (address change would create a new "customer"; i simplified my problem for the question).

I will consider the constraint, but want to check out the other suggestion first.

Comment: @MadMike . . . You probably want a type-2 table with version effective and end dates, which is yet another way to answer the question. You have probably oversimplified the question to get a useful solution.

Comment: Yes, it is simplified. The table "Customer" is actually a customer revision with validity information. When any customer information changes, including address, we will create a new row. That's why a 1:1 relationship is good enough.